How to divide large python file into small files without change program structure?
I face a program like following:
# This code just used to reflect the recursive structure, DO NOT take it grammatically !!
class A:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass
        
    def check(self, element):
        if element == 'TypeA':
            self.__validate_TypeA(element)
        if element == 'TypeB':
            self.__validate_TypeB(element)
        if element == 'TypeC':
            self.__validate_TypeC(element)
    
    def __validate_TypeA(self, element):
        # implementation..
        if element.contains('TypeB'):
            self.check('TypeB')
        # implementation...
    def __validate_TypeB(self, element):
        if element.contains('TypeC'):
            self.check('TypeC')
    def __validate_TypeC(self, element):
        if element.contains('TypeA'):
            self.check('TypeA')

    # thousands of codes here...


In this class, methods depend on each other. In my project, there are half a hundreds of types like 'TypeA', 'TypeB', and they are correlated and might call the check method on their own implementation. Now my class grows to 4 thousands lines of code, the maintaining is becoming tricky.
I have tried using inheritence, it does not work out.
I have tried using exec(), built-in, but it will forcefully break the code into multiple files, losing the possiblity of using IDE for code highlighting, etc...
So is there a way to do following?

divide my class into multiple files, might be one file for one type implementation.
do not influence the program structure

In C/C++, this could be easiliy accomplished using #include, but I do not know how to do it in Python.

Python has the same constructs as C/C++, c's #include is idiomatic to python's import

Your sample doesn't make sense. Assume you call a = A(); a.check('typeB'); then element is "typeB", which causes a.__validate_TypeB('typeB') to be invoked; 'typeB'.contains('typeC') will never be True.

@Amadan I suppose that to be illustrative - "contains" itself is not used like that for strings in Python - but it could be called with "typeBTypeC" for example.  it would work if it where testing for flat substring containship  as you suppose.
The sample however suggests me it is unfolding a testing that should be recursive, and which could take 10 , and not 10000, LoC to implement.

@chickitychinachinesechicken absolutely NOT!  #include  in C++ is just a "text paste"  operation from the programmer POV. (compilers will optimize it so that when a .h file is imported 10s of times in the same project it is not reprocessed, etc...).
The Python import statement actually executes the module being imported at runtime. SO you can't declare "some methods in the middle of a class"  in another file, and just place an import statement inside a class body.

I will give you some ideas, but you are in trouble there - if that is "real world" related, I'd suggest hiring a consulting expert in Python for some hours.
Just to take of of your suggestions out of the way: do not use exec or eval in this case - not due to security reasons, it is just dirty.
Third thing, dividing a big Python file with several functions or classes in files without changing the project structure is easy to do in Python: for each big "something.py"  file, just create a "something" directory, create inside it a __init__.py file that will import the functions and classes previously in the big file from sub-modules in that directory, and put each function group or each class in a different file inside the same something directory. Any code that made use of the something.py module will just work.
# something.py

def a():
   ...
def b():
   ...

change into
# something/file_a.py

def a():
   ...

# something/file_b.py
def b():
    ...

# something/__init__.py

from file_a import a
from file_b import b

However, you want  to subdivide classes! you can't simply slice a class into different files.
(ok, it could be made if it were really needed - creating some code to read methods declared as functions at the toplevel of submodules and patch a base class to incorporate all them would be easy . But you don't need that, and the popular static tools for Python would come nowhere near  understanding it)
Then , finally, into metaprograming and improving that code:
C/C++ source code are just "dead strings", that is why the "#include" which just performs a blind "paste" operation works.  Python code is "live" - each expression really has a runtime effect - be it perform and addition or creating a new class.
AH... a fourth thing: do not abuse the __ prefix thing just because you read somewhere it makes for "private attributes". Yes, it works mostly the same way, but thinking in private attributes just is not the way to code Python. Python is not C++ or Java, there is a reason stuff are public by default: it is simpler and more readable. Using private attributes in this way will just negate some benefits from inheritance just for start. (the mechanism for name mangling with the __ prefix is there just for the rare occasion when it is needed to avoid possible namespace clashes - not to "render an attribute invisible for my own code in other classes")
So, I can't know how close your example code is from the code you have there, but if it is like that it just looks like you'd need some recursive validation of attributes. That would take some 10-20 lines of code, no matter how many thousands of "typeA", "typeB", "typeC", etc... classes you may have inside each other.
So the last tip I will give you is to: you can get attributes and methods in a class by having the attribute or method name as a string - just use the getattr built-in function. If your code is like that, this alone can save you thousands of lines per file - if done correctly.
Sorry, with just this sample code, I can't help more. If the code is not that repetitive and you can't refactor it - there is the "ok it can be done if really needed " factor.  A Python specialist can tell you the best way to do it t a glance in a pairing-code live session, but not with this downsampled example here.
Ah, btw, did I mention that if you just remove the __ prefixes for the methods, inheritance would just work?  (well, likely it would. You did not mention which part of inheritance "did not work out")

I will second all of jsbueno's suggestions. However, to give you a literal answer to your question: you can split each method in its own file in the following way:
# some/path/a.py

from .a_validations.validate_TypeA import validate_TypeA_impl

class A:
    def check(self, element):
        # ....

    __validate_TypeA = validate_TypeA_impl


# some/path/a_validations/validate_TypeA.py

def validate_TypeA_impl(self, element):
    # ....

There is nothing special in method definitions themselves. The magic happens when they are bound to a class; it doesn't matter if you do it using def or using an assignment.
However, again, I argue against doing this, unless you really can't find a way to DRY up your code.

yes, that would work, as that code most likely will not be using the super() or __class__ special names inside the methods.
Those features can't be declared in functions and attached as methods in an easy way - the code would most likely have to hard-code the reference to the class, and work around some circular importing.  Again: not that I think the O.P. are using those.

@jsbueno Good point, thank you. However,__class__ could be just rewritten as self.__class__ though, no? Similarly, super() can be rewritten as super(self.__class__, self), unless I am mistaken. I don't see where circular importing comes in — each function will still have access to methods on self, without having to import them.

no - it is really hard, :-) ANd I figured out how hard it is when answering a question here long ago.  If you do A <- B <- C , and pass  a method inside A an instance from C, inside that method  self.__class__ will resolve to C, while __class__ is fixed in A. The parameterless super() implementation is in native code  and can't be reproduced in trivial Python code. The easy workaround if to hardcode the superclass in the calls.

I see, thank you again. I haven't done much metaprogramming in Python, and it shows :)

The cicular imort problem resulting, though, is easy to fix , once one is acquainted with the mechanisms.- one of the ways would be to inject the name A in the .a_validations module, by using code like:  validate_TypeA_impl.__globals__["A"] = A after the declartion of "A": a module's global variables is a plain (writable)  dictionary, and each function has a reference to it. This func.__globals__ reference, though, is read-only: so you can't just change the global variables of the imported function to the current module ones - but you can rewrite those globals where they are.

Or, instead of that, just declare an empty class A:  then import the functions from modules which are free to import this one (where A is declared) - and just them add the methods to A with assignments - that is by far the most common way of doing it.

do i need to import A in some/path/a_validations/validate_TypeA.py, this way is there a circular import problem?

No (unless, as @jsbueno says, you are using things like super() and __class__), your A instance methods are available on self, as usual.
